# Use existing buttons in datatables

Tags: datatables, datatables-1.10

I am trying to trigger an onClick event when click on next or previous buttons in data tables. I checked the IDs of the buttons and they are auto generated. couldn't use those IDs. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a [**`page.dt`**](https://datatables.net/reference/event/page) event, fired each time the paging is updated :

```js
table.on('page.dt', function() {
  var info = table.page.info();
  console.log('Showing page: '+info.page+' of '+info.pages);
});
```

If you want to target click on the previous / next buttons you can easily do that. To my experience dataTables seems to "eat" the click event simply by updating the view immediately - but you can stay upfront in the chain by listening on the `mousedown` event instead :

```js
$('.dataTables_wrapper').on('mousedown', '.previous', function() {
  console.log('previous clicked')
})  

$('.dataTables_wrapper').on('mousedown', '.next', function() {
  console.log('next clicked')
})
```

You need to use a delegated event handler because the dataTable controls is recreated each time the dataTable is redrawn. `.dataTables_wrapper`, `.next` and `.previous` is common for all dataTables.

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/6jpbyvd4/**